# Checked out files by all users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, list-view, check-out

Is it possible to create a view of all checked out files by all users. I already created a view to see all checked out files by the logged in user with:

> [me]

I am wondering if it is also possible for all checked out files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a View with a filter.
The condition for the filter would be:

1. Select field "Checked-out to"
2. "Is not equal to"
3. Leave value empty

And to see all files regardless of folders specifiy the Folders setting:

Folders or flat: Show all items without folders